# Deploying Preact to Heroku

Tags: heroku, preact

I've written a pretty simple app in Preact. No back end server, just front-end calling a web API and displaying the results.

I set it up on Heroku and it reports that it deployed successfully, but trying to access the app fails right out the gate:

```
2020-09-14T02:10:11.845503+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-09-14T02:10:14.403769+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
```

How should I [define a `start` script to] make this work?

In development I run `yarn dev` like the Preact docs suggest. My guess is that's just a dev server though.

FWIW, Here's my package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "clips-preact",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "preact build",
    "serve": "sirv build --port 8080 --cors --single",
    "dev": "preact watch",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "eslint-config-synacor"
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "build/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-synacor": "^3.0.4",
    "preact-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "preact": "^10.1.0",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.2",
    "recoil": "^0.0.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you start you app? how you package.json looks like ?

Comment: hello 202109 does any answer comup~~

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but to anyone who comes across this, you shouldn't be running a separate server at all.

Preact CLI builds to static output. Just point your webserver (nginx, apache) at the directory and let it handle serving the files.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "clips-preact",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "preact build",
    "serve": "sirv build --port 8080 --cors --single",
    "dev": "preact watch",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    // Your file name ↓ make sure to remove this comment before you go.
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
```

You have to add "start" inside the "scripts" area, then as you running your script type "node your_file_name" this will make "npm start" command run "node your_file_name" command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't work at all. That tries to run the index file which is not the entry point to the actual web application.

Comment: Alright, what's the entry point file you're trying to run?

Comment: Pretty sure I need to host the static files, index.html. I notice you're new to SO. I appreciate your help, but do you have experience with React/Preact/SPA, or just with nodejs?